# Android screen size inconsistency

Tags: android, android-studio, screen

As seen in this image：
[image]

I have a rounded rectangle that is the size of 1082 x 1796, and I used `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()` to get and print the pixel values of the screen as seen in the circle bottom left. However, when I draw this bitmap, this happens：
[image]

Is the screen size different from the getDefaultDisplay() method? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your shape is seen by the system as a 9patch. It use the first and last lines/columns in order to know how to resize the image in order to display it consistently.

That's why there is a 2px difference in width and height. I think you can correct it by modifying the png and removing the first and last lines/columns, or just use another way to draw the image. Maybe using another format (jpg ? bmp ?) for the image could do the job. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with calculation to fit all screen devices based on width and height of the device screen:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
                       ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

int width = dm.widthPixels;
int height = width * imageHeight / imageWidth;

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
```